# German sentence structure

Tags: verb, sentence-structure

is this correct ?

> In meiner Freizeit ich gern Bucher lesen

or this?

> In meiner Freizeit lesen ich gern Bucher

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you have doubts about. Any source text book or online grammar site will clearly give you the answer. The fact that you have the examples that you have also suggests that you have come across this topic before. So why do you have doubts?

Comment: Btw, you need to conjugate the verb "lesen". Sentence structure is nothing to worry about if conjugation isn't an automatism yet.

Comment: I don't understand where to place the verb "lesen".so you are saying I firstly need to understand  verb conjugation?

Comment: There are three mistakes: (1) German is a V2 language: In "regular" sentences the verb comes in second position, so it is: (In meiner Freizeit) (lese) (ich) (gerne.) (Verb is second). (2) You have to conjucate verbs: ich lese, not: ich lesen. (3) If you cannot type the Umlaut 'ü' in 'Bücher', then you should replace it by 'ue' - do not simply leave out the umlaut dots! -- I suppose you concentrate on one of these mistakes and rephrase your question so that it isn't about proofreading anymore.

Comment: As for conjugation... you don't have to know conjugation to understand sentence structure but sentence structure, and especially this subject verb switch takes time to sink in even if you've grasped it consciously. Conjugating however is very very basic and if you can't do that that is a real problem. Not because you can't be understood but because it sounds really really bad.

Comment: Merkwürdiger Beispielssatz. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_A._Bucher

Comment: The question about verb order is clear enough from the comparison/contrast, and two other questions were "asked" (implicitly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In German, the verb always comes second in a statement. That seems to be the gist of your question, using your example. Next time, spell it out that way.

So it begins correctly, "In meiner Freizeit" (adverbial clause).

The next thing that needs to come is the verb "lesen." But it's not the infinitive you need to use but the conjugated version (with ich), which is "lese." So of the two constructions, the second is more correct. Now the phrase reads "In meiner Freizeit **lese** ich gern..."

The last word is the plural of the word Buch, of which, the "pluralization" is as follows: ein Buch, zwei **Buecher** (if you don't have Umlauts on your keyboard), or zwei **Bücher** if you do.

So the correct, complete sentence is: "In meiner Freizeit lese ich gern Bücher."

Comment: Oder "Ich lese in meiner Freizeit gern[e] Bücher." oder "Ich lese gern[e] Bücher in meiner Freizeit."

Comment: @Robert: Those constructions follow correct word order. "Lese" is always second after "ich."

Comment: @Robert.. or "Lesen tu ich in meiner Freizeit gerne Bücher ";)

Comment: @TomAu "Lese is always second after ich" -> I know that this is clear to you, but just for the reference: a sentence does not need to start in "subject + verb". "Bücher lese ich in meiner Freizeit gern" is also a valid German sentence.

Comment: got it!!..ich lese..beacuse it's ich ,Buecher and verb comes always second..so it is  "In meiner Freizeit lese ich gern Buecher"..thankyou all!!:)